# How to use Docker Remote API to build an image using Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I store the Dockerfile in the pwd and use the Remote API "POST /build" directly to build an image, but it returns error 500 and builds nothing. My Dockerfile is correct because I build the image successfully by using the command "docker build . ". So I want to know the correct way to use this Remote API.

My Docker version is 1.11.1 and API version is 1.23